# Proxifier does not work with Backblaze

Tags: backup

Since [Backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/) doesn't support proxies (= no option to add a proxy in the settings), I want to use [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/). The latter seems to see every application I have except Backblaze. Any idea why and how I can fix it? May it be because Backblaze is registered as a service?

The connection list where Backblaze is missing:

[image]

I use Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64 and Proxifier Portable Edition 3.15.

Note that everything works fine with [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com/). I tried with ProxiCap v5.02 and the following rule:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fix: Proxifier currently does not work with Backblaze.

Comment: I encounter the same problem when using Proxifier to handle GoogleUpdate.exe. I just wonder how did you get the confirmation in your own answer?